# 2022 AdMob GDPR EEA - What happens if consent not granted

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob

I am using `react-native-google-mobile-ads` in my App to display Interstitials and Rewarded Ads. Currently, I am trying to handle the EEA consent correctly.

This is my code:

```
const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  ...ADS_REQUEST_OPTIONS,
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: !userChoices.selectPersonalisedAds,
});
```

Here is my code:

1. *config.js*:

```
export const TEST_DEVICE_ID = "EMULATOR";

export const INFO_REQUEST_CONFIGURATION = {
  tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,
  testDeviceIdentifiers: [TEST_DEVICE_ID],
  // Always ensure debug information is removed for production apps!
  ...__DEV__ && { debugGeography: AdsConsentDebugGeography.EEA },
};

export const ADS_REQUEST_CONFIGURATION = {
  maxAdContentRating: MaxAdContentRating.T,
  tagForChildDirectedTreatment: false,
  tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,
  testDeviceIdentifiers: [TEST_DEVICE_ID],
};

export const ADS_REQUEST_OPTIONS = {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: false,
  keywords: [
    ...
  ],
};
```

2. *AdMobContext.jsx*:

```
...

export function AdMobProvider({ children }) {
  const requestEEAConsent = async () => {
    const consentInfo = await AdsConsent.requestInfoUpdate(INFO_REQUEST_CONFIGURATION);

    if (
      consentInfo.isConsentFormAvailable &&
      consentInfo.status === AdsConsentStatus.REQUIRED
    ) {
      const { status } = await AdsConsent.showForm();

      consentInfo.status = status;
    }

    console.log({ consentInfo });

    return consentInfo;
  };

  const initializeAdmob = async () => {
    // Request the respective consent to users in the EEA
    await requestEEAConsent();

    // Configure the ads requests
    await mobileAds().setRequestConfiguration(ADS_REQUEST_CONFIGURATION);

    // Initialize the AdMob service
    await mobileAds().initialize();
  };

   useEffect(() => {
    initializeAdmob();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  
   ...
}
```

**Will AdMob display ads to users that have not granted the consent?**

**Do we have to handle this manually or does AdMob manage this for us?**

Comment: Figure anything out?